# MP4 video - edit audio track

Tags: audio, mp4

I have recorded some nice sport videos with mz GoPro HD action camera.

I would like to edit the audio track. I dont want to get rid of the whole audio track - just erase small parts (e.g. compression artifacts or me saying some swearwords). When the original audio track is cleansed, Id add another music layer in FCE afterwards.
I'd really like to edit the audio like in a WaveLab etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a Mac for this?

Answer (score 1):

Any good NLE package should allow you to do this.

The most popular and probably the best applications available are

Adobe Premiere Pro (Mac & PC), Final Cut Pro (Mac Only), Sony Vegas (PC Only)